# jQuery changes elements after page has rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On my site I have Wordpress creating a menu. I have some jQuery that makes changes to that menu to make it a responsive menu. This works just fine. My problem is that when you load the page you see the normal menu and then it changes to the responsive menu. This leads me to believe that the jQuery is running after the page has rendered rather then before. I have tried everything I could find on Google to fix the issue, but since I don't know the exact issue, I am not even sure I am trying the right fixes.

I have loaded the Javascript file in the footer and the header. I have also changed the order that the CSS that comes with the Javascript is loaded. I even went as far as to add a class to the body tag that has its visibility set to none and then at the end of the footer I had some Javascript that removed the class from the body tag so that all you see until the page is fully rendered is a white page, but that didn't help either. You could still see the menu change even after the class was removed from the body tag.

If you want to see this happen for yourself, just go to this link.
https://www.cheekypunter.com

Otherwise, here is the code used for the menu.

```js
/*

Responsive Mobile Menu v1.0
Plugin URI: responsivemobilemenu.com

Author: Sergio Vitov
Author URI: http://xmacros.com

License: CC BY 3.0 http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/

*/

function responsiveMobileMenu() {
  jQuery('.rmm').each(function() {



    jQuery(this).children('ul').addClass('rmm-main-list');  // mark main menu list


    var $style = jQuery(this).attr('data-menu-style');  // get menu style
    if ( typeof $style == 'undefined' ||  $style == false )
    {
      jQuery(this).addClass('graphite'); // set graphite style if style is not defined
    }
    else {
      jQuery(this).addClass($style);
    }


    /*   width of menu list (non-toggled) */

    var $width = 0;
    jQuery(this).find('ul li').each(function() {
      $width += jQuery(this).outerWidth();
    });

    // if modern browser

    if (jQuery.support.leadingWhitespace) {
      jQuery(this).css('max-width' , '1024px');
    }
    //
    else {
      jQuery(this).css('width' , '1024px');
    }

  });
}
function getMobileMenu() {

  /*   build toggled dropdown menu list */

  jQuery('.rmm').each(function() {
    var menutitle = jQuery(this).attr("data-menu-title");
    if ( menutitle == "" ) {
      menutitle = "Menu";
    }
    else if ( menutitle == undefined ) {
      menutitle = "Menu";
    }
    var $menulist = jQuery(this).children('.rmm-main-list').html();
    var $menucontrols ="<div class='rmm-toggled-controls'><div class='rmm-toggled-title'>" + menutitle + "</div><div class='rmm-button'><span>&nbsp;</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span>&nbsp;</span></div></div>";
    jQuery(this).prepend("<div class='rmm-toggled rmm-closed'>"+$menucontrols+"<ul>"+$menulist+"</ul></div>");

  });
}

function adaptMenu() {

  /*   toggle menu on resize */

  jQuery('.rmm').each(function() {
    var $width = jQuery(this).css('max-width');
    $width = $width.replace('px', '');
    if ( jQuery(this).parent().width() < 1020 ) {
      jQuery(this).children('.rmm-main-list').hide(0);
      jQuery(this).children('.rmm-toggled').show(0);
    }
    else {
      jQuery(this).children('.rmm-main-list').show(0);
      jQuery(this).children('.rmm-toggled').hide(0);
    }
  });

}

jQuery(function() {

  responsiveMobileMenu();
  getMobileMenu();
  adaptMenu();

  /* slide down mobile menu on click */

  jQuery('.rmm-toggled, .rmm-toggled .rmm-button').click(function(){
    if ( jQuery(this).is(".rmm-closed")) {
      jQuery(this).find('ul').stop().show(300);
      jQuery(this).removeClass("rmm-closed");
    }
    else {
      jQuery(this).find('ul').stop().hide(300);
      jQuery(this).addClass("rmm-closed");
    }

  });
});
/*   hide mobile menu on resize */
jQuery(window).resize(function() {
  adaptMenu();
});
```

```css
#header-navigation { font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; font-weight: 700; font-size: 16px; clear: both; background: #b40610; box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px #b40610;}
.header-nav-menu { display: table; list-style: none; max-width: 1024px; width: 100% !important; margin: 0px auto; padding: 0px;}
.header-nav-menu li {  display: table-cell; text-align: center;}
.header-nav-menu li a { display: block; color: #ffffff;    text-decoration: none; white-space: nowrap; padding: 12px 0px;}
.header-nav-menu li a:hover { color: #00005c; background: #e8eaf1; }

.rmm {
 display:block;
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
 padding:0px;
 margin:0 auto !important;
 line-height:19px !important;
}
.rmm * {
 -webkit-tap-highlight-color:transparent !important;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.rmm a {
 color:#ebebeb;
 text-decoration:none;
}
.rmm .rmm-main-list, .rmm .rmm-main-list li {
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
}
.rmm ul {
 width:auto;
 margin:0 auto !important;
 overflow:hidden;
 list-style:none;
}


/* sublevel menu - in construction */
.rmm ul li ul, .rmm ul li ul li, .rmm ul li ul li a {
 display:none !important;
 height:0px !important;
 width:0px !important;
}
/* */


.rmm .rmm-main-list li {
 display:inline;
 padding:0px;
 margin:0px !important;
}
.rmm-toggled {
 display:none;
 width:100%;
 position:relative;
 overflow:hidden;
 margin:0 auto !important;
}
.rmm-button:hover {
 cursor:pointer;
}
.rmm .rmm-toggled ul {
 display:none;
 margin:0px !important;
 padding:0px !important;
}
.rmm .rmm-toggled ul li {
 display:block;
 margin:0 auto !important;
}




/* GRAPHITE STYLE */

.rmm.graphite .rmm-main-list li a {
 display:inline-block;
 padding:15px 25px;
 margin:0px -3px 0px -3px;
}
.rmm.graphite .rmm-toggled {
 width:95%;
 min-height:36px;
 border-radius:6px;
}
.rmm.graphite .rmm-toggled-controls {
 display:block;
 height:36px;
 color:white;
 text-align:left;
 position:relative;
 border-radius:6px;
}
.rmm.graphite .rmm-toggled-title {
 position:relative;
 top:9px;
 left:15px;
 font-size:16px;
 color:white;
 text-shadow:1px 1px 1px black;
}
.rmm.graphite .rmm-button {
 display:block;
 position:absolute;
 right:15px;
 top:8px;
}

.rmm.graphite .rmm-button span {
 display:block;
 margin-top:4px;
 height:2px;
 background:white;
 width:24px;
}
.rmm.graphite .rmm-toggled ul li a {
 display:block;
 width:100%;
 text-align:center;
 padding:10px 0px 10px 0px;
 border-bottom:1px solid #ffffff;
}
.rmm.graphite .rmm-toggled ul li a:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;
}
.rmm.graphite .rmm-toggled ul li a:active {
 background-color:#444444;
 border-bottom:1px solid #444444;
 border-top:1px solid #444444;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="header-navigation">
  <div class="rmm">
    <ul id="menu-primary" class="header-nav-menu">
      <li id="menu-item-412" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-home menu-item-412"><a href="https://www.cheekypunter.com/">Home</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-434" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-434"><a href="https://www.cheekypunter.com/about/">About</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-436" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-436"><a href="/tips/">Tips</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-433" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-433"><a href="https://www.cheekypunter.com/free-bets/">Offers</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-435" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-page-ancestor menu-item-435"><a href="https://www.cheekypunter.com/reviews/">Reviews</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-4554" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-4554"><a href="/stats/">Stats</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-893" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-893"><a href="/mobile/">Apps</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-894" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-894"><a href="/deposit/">Banking</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping it in a [**`$(document).ready()`**](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)?

Comment: It's already there (`jQuery(function()`) @ObsidianAge, after the 3 named functions.

Comment: I have wrapped it in .ready() as well as .load() and neither fixed it.

Comment: jQuery or even JavaScript are designed to do jobs like this

Comment: jQuery's ```$(document).ready()``` method is designed to be triggered after the DOM has been fully loaded , that's why you're having this issue.
I suggest you to read about CSS media queries here:
http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries
Once you understand the media queries , take a look at this responsive menu bar:
http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav_responsive.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the page is finishing loading before the responsive mobile menu code runs is because your code which changes the menu is wrapped in

```
jQuery(function() {
//...
});
```

, which is equivalent to `$(document).ready()`, ie it tells the browser to wait until the document has finished loading before running the code.

You could try taking your responsive mobile menu scripts and instead inserting them into their own script tag inserted into the HTML immediately below the menu to which they apply, and removing the `jQuery(function() {...});` wrapper. See code snippet below for a working example of what I mean:

```css
#header-navigation { font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; font-weight: 700; font-size: 16px; clear: both; background: #b40610; box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px #b40610;}
.header-nav-menu { display: table; list-style: none; max-width: 1024px; width: 100% !important; margin: 0px auto; padding: 0px;}
.header-nav-menu li {  display: table-cell; text-align: center;}
.header-nav-menu li a { display: block; color: #ffffff;    text-decoration: none; white-space: nowrap; padding: 12px 0px;}
.header-nav-menu li a:hover { color: #00005c; background: #e8eaf1; }

.rmm {
 display:block;
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
 padding:0px;
 margin:0 auto !important;
 line-height:19px !important;
}
.rmm * {
 -webkit-tap-highlight-color:transparent !important;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.rmm a {
 color:#ebebeb;
 text-decoration:none;
}
.rmm .rmm-main-list, .rmm .rmm-main-list li {
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
}
.rmm ul {
 width:auto;
 margin:0 auto !important;
 overflow:hidden;
 list-style:none;
}


/* sublevel menu - in construction */
.rmm ul li ul, .rmm ul li ul li, .rmm ul li ul li a {
 display:none !important;
 height:0px !important;
 width:0px !important;
}
/* */


.rmm .rmm-main-list li {
 display:inline;
 padding:0px;
 margin:0px !important;
}
.rmm-toggled {
 display:none;
 width:100%;
 position:relative;
 overflow:hidden;
 margin:0 auto !important;
}
.rmm-button:hover {
 cursor:pointer;
}
.rmm .rmm-toggled ul {
 display:none;
 margin:0px !important;
 padding:0px !important;
}
.rmm .rmm-toggled ul li {
 display:block;
 margin:0 auto !important;
}




/* GRAPHITE STYLE */

.rmm.graphite .rmm-main-list li a {
 display:inline-block;
 padding:15px 25px;
 margin:0px -3px 0px -3px;
}
.rmm.graphite .rmm-toggled {
 width:95%;
 min-height:36px;
 border-radius:6px;
}
.rmm.graphite .rmm-toggled-controls {
 display:block;
 height:36px;
 color:white;
 text-align:left;
 position:relative;
 border-radius:6px;
}
.rmm.graphite .rmm-toggled-title {
 position:relative;
 top:9px;
 left:15px;
 font-size:16px;
 color:white;
 text-shadow:1px 1px 1px black;
}
.rmm.graphite .rmm-button {
 display:block;
 position:absolute;
 right:15px;
 top:8px;
}

.rmm.graphite .rmm-button span {
 display:block;
 margin-top:4px;
 height:2px;
 background:white;
 width:24px;
}
.rmm.graphite .rmm-toggled ul li a {
 display:block;
 width:100%;
 text-align:center;
 padding:10px 0px 10px 0px;
 border-bottom:1px solid #ffffff;
}
.rmm.graphite .rmm-toggled ul li a:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;
}
.rmm.graphite .rmm-toggled ul li a:active {
 background-color:#444444;
 border-bottom:1px solid #444444;
 border-top:1px solid #444444;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="header-navigation">
  <div class="rmm">
    <ul id="menu-primary" class="header-nav-menu">
      <li id="menu-item-412" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-home menu-item-412"><a href="https://www.cheekypunter.com/">Home</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-434" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-434"><a href="https://www.cheekypunter.com/about/">About</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-436" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-436"><a href="/tips/">Tips</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-433" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-433"><a href="https://www.cheekypunter.com/free-bets/">Offers</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-435" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-page-ancestor menu-item-435"><a href="https://www.cheekypunter.com/reviews/">Reviews</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-4554" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-4554"><a href="/stats/">Stats</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-893" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-893"><a href="/mobile/">Apps</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-894" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-894"><a href="/deposit/">Banking</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
<script>/*

Responsive Mobile Menu v1.0
Plugin URI: responsivemobilemenu.com

Author: Sergio Vitov
Author URI: http://xmacros.com

License: CC BY 3.0 http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/

*/

function responsiveMobileMenu() {
  jQuery('.rmm').each(function() {



    jQuery(this).children('ul').addClass('rmm-main-list');  // mark main menu list


    var $style = jQuery(this).attr('data-menu-style');  // get menu style
    if ( typeof $style == 'undefined' ||  $style == false )
    {
      jQuery(this).addClass('graphite'); // set graphite style if style is not defined
    }
    else {
      jQuery(this).addClass($style);
    }


    /*   width of menu list (non-toggled) */

    var $width = 0;
    jQuery(this).find('ul li').each(function() {
      $width += jQuery(this).outerWidth();
    });

    // if modern browser

    if (jQuery.support.leadingWhitespace) {
      jQuery(this).css('max-width' , '1024px');
    }
    //
    else {
      jQuery(this).css('width' , '1024px');
    }

  });
}
function getMobileMenu() {

  /*   build toggled dropdown menu list */

  jQuery('.rmm').each(function() {
    var menutitle = jQuery(this).attr("data-menu-title");
    if ( menutitle == "" ) {
      menutitle = "Menu";
    }
    else if ( menutitle == undefined ) {
      menutitle = "Menu";
    }
    var $menulist = jQuery(this).children('.rmm-main-list').html();
    var $menucontrols ="<div class='rmm-toggled-controls'><div class='rmm-toggled-title'>" + menutitle + "</div><div class='rmm-button'><span>&nbsp;</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span>&nbsp;</span></div></div>";
    jQuery(this).prepend("<div class='rmm-toggled rmm-closed'>"+$menucontrols+"<ul>"+$menulist+"</ul></div>");

  });
}

function adaptMenu() {

  /*   toggle menu on resize */

  jQuery('.rmm').each(function() {
    var $width = jQuery(this).css('max-width');
    $width = $width.replace('px', '');
    if ( jQuery(this).parent().width() < 1020 ) {
      jQuery(this).children('.rmm-main-list').hide(0);
      jQuery(this).children('.rmm-toggled').show(0);
    }
    else {
      jQuery(this).children('.rmm-main-list').show(0);
      jQuery(this).children('.rmm-toggled').hide(0);
    }
  });

}

  responsiveMobileMenu();
  getMobileMenu();
  adaptMenu();

  /* slide down mobile menu on click */

  jQuery('.rmm-toggled, .rmm-toggled .rmm-button').click(function(){
    if ( jQuery(this).is(".rmm-closed")) {
      jQuery(this).find('ul').stop().show(300);
      jQuery(this).removeClass("rmm-closed");
    }
    else {
      jQuery(this).find('ul').stop().hide(300);
      jQuery(this).addClass("rmm-closed");
    }

  });

/*   hide mobile menu on resize */
jQuery(window).resize(function() {
  adaptMenu();
});</script>
```

Note that you absolutely must wait until at least the navigation has loaded in the DOM before you can manipulate it with jQuery (or any JavaScript) - you can't manipulate what isn't there - so by running the scripts immediately after that part of the DOM loads is the soonest you can run them.

IMO a cleaner solution which would avoid these problems would be to simply have a responsive menu that is made responsive with just CSS and media queries rather than made responsive with jQuery; it is perfectly possible to make a responsive mobile menu without jQuery and you would avoid all of these sorts of problems.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I partly used what you suggested. Rather than adding all the Javascript in a script tag under the menu, I just added the 3 function calls and that seems to have worked.

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is that when you load the page you see the normal menu and then it changes to the responsive menu. This leads me to believe that the jQuery is running after the page has rendered rather then before.

True, jQuery runs "after". At it needs to because in the 3 functions you have to make it a mobile menu, there are some `width` value retreiving from rendered element... And then some comparisons to show/hide some elements...

The issue is this is visible to the user for a split second.

As a mitigation solution more than a fix, you could try to play with the `opacity` of the header... Maybe you'll like the effect!

In your CSS, add:

```
#header{
  opacity:0;
}
```

After the 3 functions, add:

```
setTimeout(()=>{
  $("#header").animate({"opacity":1},800);
},800);
```

This will wait 800ms to start something like a fade in animation over another 800ms.
That should be way enought to "hide" the header while it self-adjusts.

Disclaimer: I'm not sure that will work. But I would try. ;)

Comment: A real "fix" would be to remove all that display adjustment scripts and re-desing your header using CSS [@media rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media)... So it all depends on your actual level of satisfaction of the actual display versus the time you want to spend on it. ;)

Comment: That's basically the same thing I did with adding the class to body that had visibility hidden except your suggestion adds a delay. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: But hiding the element will mess the width comparisons... Since an hidden element has no width/height. Opacity does not affect dimentions. ;)